# Add user accessible files-Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an application in which it lets the user access the files in a particular path ,eg-Environment,getExternalStorageDirectory. It is functional but I want the application to be independent.Is there a way to keep html files inside your project and let the user access them using BrowserIntent?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

you can save in `assets/` directory ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Vincenzo,I had tried that but how can I give access to the users?